# Yosemite: is there a way to define a default application to open unknown file types?

Tags: finder, osx-yosemite

I'm on Yosemite,
I've got the feeling to waste a lot of time choosing an App every time the Finder
doesn't know how to handle a file type.

I would like to say a simple thing:  by default, use Smultron (or any other app).
Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify for *any* unknown file type (or not easily), only for each specific file type as you acquire a file of that type.
Many file types will already have a default, even if that's the first time the Mac has seen that type.

If you right click a file & select 'Open With >' you will see a list of all applications that are able to handle it in some way, with a Default application at the top.

If you want to change the default, in the following example for a tasty Chicken Paprika recipe (which is a text file with embedded pictures, .rtfd) from TextEdit to TextWrangler…

[image]

…then select Show Info, further down the right-click menu keyboard equivalent is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>

Changing the drop menu in the red outline to TextWrangler will make TextWrangler the default for *just that file* & in future double-clicking it will launch TextWrangler instead of TextEdit.

If you want *all* .rtfd files to open in TextWrangler, then click the 'change all' button just underneath.

Note in this specific example, that will affect all .rtfd text files, but not .rtf or .txt or anything else - allowing you to use a different default for every type of text file, should you so wish.
Repeat the process on a .txt file, if that's what you need.

[image]

Comment: This is easy, question is asking for any unknown ones. As a programmer you need to edit files with an arbitrary extension all the time - going through this settings each time becomes tiresome quickly

Comment: @Ev0oD - you're quite welcome to come up with your own answer if you've found a way to do it in the 4½ years since this question was asked.